# Pandas: count some value in all columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe

```
graph   0       1       2       3       4
1       blue    blue    blue    blue    blue
2       blue    blue    blue    blue    blue
3       blue    red     blue    blue    red
4       red     blue    red     red     blue
5       red     red     blue    red     red
6       blue    blue    blue    blue    blue
```

I need to get the count of the value 'blue' of every string/line.
The desired output:

```
graph   result
1       5
2       5
3       3
4       2
5       1
6       5
```

I try to do it with

```
(df['0', '1', '2', '3', '4']).applymap(lambda x: str.count(x, 'blue'))
```

But it returns

```
KeyError: ('0', '1', '2', '3', '4')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [35]: df.set_index('graph').eq('blue').sum(1).reset_index(name='result')
Out[35]:
   graph  result
0      1       5
1      2       5
2      3       3
3      4       2
4      5       1
5      6       5
```

Answer (score 1):

With a `numpy` bent.  Reconstruct from scratch if you reliably know where the `graph` column is, namely column `0`.

```
v = df.values
pd.DataFrame(dict(graph=v[:, 0], result=(df.values[:, 1:] == 'blue').sum(1)))

  graph  result
0     1       5
1     2       5
2     3       3
3     4       2
4     5       1
5     6       5
```

***naive time test***
[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per [`pandas.DataFrame.eq`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html):

Get Equal to of dataframe and other, element-wise (binary operator eq).

Among flexible wrappers (`eq`, `ne`, `le`, `lt`, `ge`, `gt`) to comparison operators.

Equivalent to ==, =!, <=, <, >=, > with support to choose axis (rows or columns) and level for comparison.

Not just for using for numbers.

Hope this information is helpful