# Convert text table to pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, text-editor

Many times when I'm trying to answer questions on Stackoverflow, the question contains a table, which I have to convert to a pandas dataframe in order to process. for example, in this question:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172116/pandas-count-some-value-in-all-columns
```

My question is, is there a faster way to convert it to a dataframe rather than writing:

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'graph':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
0:['blue','blue','red','red','blue','blue'],
1:['blue','blue','red','blue','red','blue'],
2:['blue','blue','blue','red','blue','blue'],
3:['blue','blue','blue','red','red','blue'],
4:['blue','blue','red','blue','red','blue']})
```

given that I can copy the text:

```
graph   0       1       2       3       4
1       blue    blue    blue    blue    blue
2       blue    blue    blue    blue    blue
3       blue    red     blue    blue    red
4       red     blue    red     red     blue
5       red     red     blue    red     red
6       blue    blue    blue    blue    blue
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure the desired data set is in clipboard and use [pd.read_clipboard()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_clipboard.html) method.

Step by step:

1. mark desired data set
2. press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (for MS Windows)
3. execute: `df = pd.read_clipboard()`

---

```
In [40]: df = pd.read_clipboard()

In [41]: df
Out[41]:
   graph     0     1     2     3     4
0      1  blue  blue  blue  blue  blue
1      2  blue  blue  blue  blue  blue
2      3  blue   red  blue  blue   red
3      4   red  blue   red   red  blue
4      5   red   red  blue   red   red
5      6  blue  blue  blue  blue  blue
```

Comment: @beniev, sorry, i don't understand that: `shorten the quotes addition to each string`