# Summing column tallies

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe called `Votes` and I am trying to figure out how many missing values are in the data frame represented as `'?'`. The Data Frame has `header=none` so the column titles are listed as `0`, `1`, `2` etc. I used the following code:

```
Empty = Votes.loc[:,:] == '?'
```

to find the missing data, and then sum up the column tallies
to create a boolean to find missing data. I would like to sum the column tallies that indicate the missing value to see how many missing values are in the dataframe. I used the code:

```
sum(Empty.sum())
```

to get the total but was unable to do it by column. How could I find the total by summing the column tallies?

Comment: Not flagging because is not exact dups, but these 2 could get you in the right direction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32589829/how-to-get-value-counts-for-multiple-columns-at-once-in-pandas-dataframe ; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43172116/pandas-count-some-value-in-all-columns

Comment: From the links that @Tomerikoo shared, I would do something like this:
  import pandas as pd
    votes = pd.DataFrame({0 : [3,5,'?',7],
             1 : ['?',4,'?',12],
             2 : [1,'?','?',7]})

    votes.apply(pd.value_counts).loc['?'].astype(int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much just do what you tried doing but do it for each column not the whole `DataFrame`. A `dict` might be a good way to organize it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    0:[1,2,'?',4,5,'?',7],
    1:['?',2,'?',4,'?',6,7],
    2:['?',2,'?',4,5,'?','?'],
})

empty = {c:(df[c] == '?').sum() for c in df.columns}

for k,v in empty.items():
    print(f'Column {k} has a total of {v} missing values.')
```

[Example In Python Tutor](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#code=import%20pandas%20as%20pd%0A%0Adf%20%3D%20pd.DataFrame%28%7B%0A%20%20%20%200%3A%5B1,2,'%3F',4,5,'%3F',7%5D,%0A%20%20%20%201%3A%5B'%3F',2,'%3F',4,'%3F',6,7%5D,%0A%20%20%20%202%3A%5B'%3F',2,'%3F',4,5,'%3F','%3F'%5D,%0A%7D%29%0A%0Aempty%20%3D%20%7Bc%3A%28df%5Bc%5D%20%3D%3D%20'%3F'%29.sum%28%29%20for%20c%20in%20df.columns%7D%0A%0Afor%20k,v%20in%20empty.items%28%29%3A%0A%20%20%20%20print%28f'Column%20%7Bk%7D%20has%20a%20total%20of%20%7Bv%7D%20missing%20values.'%29&cumulative=true&curInstr=5&heapPrimitives=false&mode=display&origin=opt-frontend.js&py=py3anaconda&rawInputLstJSON=%5B%5D&textReferences=false)

Comment: Thank you! I will try.